# Why when I update a useState it updates another one without having called it (react hooks)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am taking my first steps in react and in the programming itself, and for this I am making a simple shopping cart, which allows me to add the products that I am going to buy to a useState that starts with an empty array. I also have the products in another useState. When I add the product through a button that has the addProduct function, it verifies if the product is already in the list and if so, it increases the amount if it is not added. The problem is that when the product is already it increases the amount well but it also does it in the products which is in another useState. From this I take the extension of chrome components and because when I remove the product from the shopping list and put it back, it adds it to me, but this time with the amount that was last time.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AvailableProductsList } from "./components/AvailableProductsList";
import { ShoppingListCart } from "./components/ShoppingListCart";

export const App = () => {
  // useState that has the products available
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Apple", description: "Apple x 6", amount: 1, price: 3000 },
    { id: 2, name: "Rice", description: "Rice x 1 lb", amount: 1, price: 4000 },
  ]);

  // useState which creates the shopping cart list for me
  const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState([]);

  // Function to add products to the cart or to increase the quantity of some
  const addProduct = (id) => {
    if (shoppingList.some((product) => product.id === id)) {
      const increaseQuantity = shoppingList.map((product) => {
        if (product.id === id) {
          product.amount++;
          return product;
        } else {
          return product;
        }
      });

      setShoppingList(increaseQuantity);
    } else {
      const addNew = products.filter((product) => product.id === id);
      setShoppingList([...shoppingList, ...addNew]);
    }
  };

  // Function to remove products from the shopping list (shopping list cart)
  const removeProduct = (id) => {
    const remove = shoppingList.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
    setShoppingList(remove);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row border border-2 border-danger">
        <div className="col-6 border border-info">
          <div className="row">
            {products.map((product) => (
              <AvailableProductsList
                key={product.id}
                product={product}
                addProduct={addProduct}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-6">
          {shoppingList.map((product) => (
            <ShoppingListCart
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              removeProduct={removeProduct}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the below code

```
 if (product.id === id) {
   product.amount++;
   return product;
 } else {
   return product;
 }
```

Change it to

```
if (product.id === id) {
  return { ...product, amount: product.amount + 1 };
}
return product;
```

Poduct is referred from products array. Don't mutate it directly. Create a copy of it and then do the changes